# Telegram Auto forward

Tags: telegram

I have subscribed to a couple of paid alerts which sends me alert on the critical financial events on telegram via telegram-bot.

I intend to develop an application that captures such messages which are sent by these bots and store in the database.

Is it possible to do it in telegram ? (telegram is only option.  I can create other 'special ID or somekind of BOT and share this my custom bot with companies which are sending alert)

thanks in advance.